# how to use logged in user image in Cakephp with Cakedc plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakedc

how to check the image of user in cakephp 3.0 with cakedc plugin. There are two tables one for users and other for social account details. I want to how to do i fetch images for normal user and other who use login with facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many plugins available to upload images and process them (crop, resize etc) in CakePHP, check this list https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#imagery and https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp#files. Then you'll need to extend the CakeDC Users Plugin to attach the upload related behavior, follow the documentation to extend the Users Table here https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Extending-the-Plugin.md#extending-the-model-tableentity

Note this will depend a lot on the upload plugin selected, but most of them will provide a behavior you'll need to attach to the Users Table.

Then override the users edit/add templates to add the required file fields for the avatar image upload.